# How to get own $UID in ant?

Tags: ant

```
$ echo $UID # return my user ID
```

I want to use this information within an ant-buildfile. A solution is to set this variable explicitly:

```
ant some-target -DOWNER_UID=$UID
```

This way, in my buildfile "${OWNER_ID}" is available for usage.

Is there a way to get this information within the buildfile in an "internal" way, without the need to pass the $UID as parameter?

Comment: The UID is an OS specific property. Would the user name be ok instead? If so it is available as the following java property: ${user.name}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a cross-platform solution, but the following is likely to work in most Unix-like environments:

```
<exec executable="id" failonerror="true" outputproperty="uid">
    <arg value="--user"/>
</exec>

<echo>uid: ${uid}</echo>
```

Comment: Looks promising, I will try this soon!

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about accessing an environment variable ($UID) in Ant, you can do like this:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<echo>UID: ${env.UID}</echo>
```

See the documentation for the [Property task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).

Comment: In the OP's env the var is $UID not $OWNER_UID - maybe edit to reflect that?

Comment: I guess sudocode is copying my parameter "OWNER_ID", which is not an env-parameter, indeed.
I want to have s.th. like "env.UID" (getting $UID from system), but at least on my system(s) this parameter is not resolved (property environmen ... is set).

Comment: Thanks Martin, I updated to match the environment variable name. Marcus, is the environment variable exported before you execute Ant?

Comment: ${env.UID} is not exported, no. This is my question about, I want to get host-$UID without the need to give anything to ant. The other answer by Chad solved my issue. Thanks anyhow!